# Rails/Haml: adding a parentclass every n iteration

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm, haml

I have a photo gallery that is organised like this:

```
.container
  %li
    %a{src: image.src}
  %li
    %a{src: image.src}
  %li
    %a{src: image.src}

.container
  %li
    %a{src: image.src}
  %li
    %a{src: image.src}
  %li
    %a{src: image.src}
```

Each container should have a maximum of 3 `%li`.

Let's say I have `@images` where `@images.count => 4`.

```
.container
  - for image in @images do
    %li
      %a{src: image.src}
```

This code will break the page because in this case `.container` has 4 `%li`.

How can I do so that a `.container` gets added every 3 `%li` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess method [Array#in_groups_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of) is what you looking for.

```
- @images.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |images|
  .container
    - images.each do |image|
      %li
        %a{src: image.src}
```

By the way, using this this method you can also define replacement for missing images

```
%w(1 2 3 4).in_groups_of(3, '_') {|group| p group}
# => ["1", "2", "3"]
# => ["4", "_", "_"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
- @images.each_slice(3) do |images|
  .container
    - images.each do |image|
      %li
        %a{src: image.src}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using ruby's each_slice method on @images
http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice

```
- @images.each_slice(3) do |i| ....
```